# ADB Shell Command to Grant Storage Permissions on Android 11

Tags: android, adb, android-permissions

The following shell command doesn't work on Android 11 devices. Can someone help me with an alternative?

```
adb shell pm grant com.adobe.reader android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
adb shell appops set --uid PACKAGE_NAME MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE allow
```

Read more here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#enable-manage-external-storage-for-testing

Answer (score -1):

***Kotlin working Code***

*Dependencies to be added in build.gradle*

`androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:rules:1.3.0"`

***Code :***

```
@get:Rule
   val permissionRule: GrantPermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(
    CAMERA, CALL_PHONE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
   )
```